# Java NIO - non-blocking connect

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

In a non-blocking connect on the client side, it might be the case that the server is not up and the connection cannot be established. I use selector to wait for OP_CONNECT to figure out if the connection can be established in the following way:

```
connection = SocketChannel.open();
connection.configureBlocking(false);

// Kick off connection establishment
connection.connect(hostAddress);

connection.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
this.selector.select(2000);

// Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
if (!selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("\"Could not connect to \" + hostAddress");
}
SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
boolean valid = key.isValid();

if (!key.isConnectable()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("\"Could not connect to \" + hostAddress");
}
finishConnection(key);
```

However, even if I do not start the server, the `key.isConnectable()` returns true... I don;t understand why that is the case and how to make sure that I only call `selector.select()` again when I am connected

Comment: Just for info: If you don't need the low level NIO stuff, take a look at Netty: http://netty.io/ It makes non-blocking IO super easy.

Comment: There's not much point to doing it this way. All you're doing here is implementing blocking mode yourself with a select(). It this is what your real code does, it would be simpler to leave the channel in blocking mode, use connect() with a timeout parameter, and go into non-blocking mode on successful connection. Actually I see little need for NIO in TCP clients at all.